# How to scrape dynamic content with Selenium in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape the following page: https://www.heo.co.uk/uk/en/product/FRYU40156

I understand that this is a dynamic website so using the classic Request & Beautiful Soup combo might not work. I'm trying using Selenium and I do get more information by I can't seem to get the following: [image of the bit I'm trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zM0eB.png)

I've tried to use By.TAG_NAME and 'h1' but it does not work.

Any ideas of how I can get the header ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to network tab you will get the following api

[image]

> https://www.heo.co.uk/api/article

Use the api to get the header value

```
import requests
payload={
  "articleNumber": "FRYU40156",
  "language": "en"
}
r=requests.post("https://www.heo.co.uk/api/article",data=payload).json()
print(r['article']['localization']['deName'])
```

**output:**

```
Jujutsu Kaisen 0: The Movie Hikkake PVC Statue Satoru Gojo 10 cm
```

Comment: you are my hero